# Accessing member functions through pointers

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Why am I getting the address in the output. Rather I should get the Output Length= (value input by user) , Width = (value input by user).
As in the main body of program after getting input `R1.getdata()` , `ptr->result()` should display the result of Rectangle class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
   protected:
    float length;
    float width;

   public:
    void getdata() {
        cout << "Enter length and width= ";
        cin >> length >> width;
    }
    void result() {
        cout << "Length = " << length << "\nWidth = " << width << endl;
    }
};
class Area : public Rectangle {
   private:
    float area;

   public:
    void calc_area() { area = length * width; }
    void result() { cout << "Area = " << area << endl; }
};
class Perimeter : public Rectangle {
   private:
    float perimeter;

   public:
    void calc_peri() { perimeter = 2 * (length + width); }
    void result() { cout << "Perimeter = " << perimeter << endl; }
};
void main() {
    Rectangle R1;
    Area A1;
    Perimeter P1;
    Rectangle *ptr;
    R1.getdata();
    ptr = &A1;
    ptr->result();
}
```

Comment: Please do show your output (as well as the build command), and where you are "getting the address in the output". Did you mean that you're getting the *area* in the output?

Comment: Did you mean to make `result()`  a `virtual` function?

Comment: You are calling `getdata` and `result` on different objects.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to add image because I don't have much points.

Comment: I am not getting the area as it is not virtual. But the output is length=some address width=some address  

 
Rather it should give Length = (Value input by user) Width= (Value input by user)

Comment: You're reading into `R1`, but printing the result in `A1`, which only has uninitialised members. What you call "address" is just a very large number. (In what twisted world is "perimeter" and "area" two different *kinds* of rectangles?)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the wrong values, because you are calling  `ptr->result();` on a uninitialized Area object (A1), which has been upcasted from pointer to Rectangle object.

The values the user inputs though are used in the `R1` object, which you then don't use anymore. Moreover, you should make the `result()` method virtual.

Lastly, the **syntax for calling base class method on a pointer to an inheriting class is**: `ptr->Rectangle::result();`.

Below you will find your code with some fixes that demonstrate things I wrote about:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Rectangle {
   protected:
    float length;
    float width;

   public:
    void getdata() {
        cout << "Enter length and width= ";
        cin >> length >> width;
        std::cout << length << "  " << width << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void result() {
        cout << "(Rectangle) Length = " << length << "\nWidth = " << width
             << endl;
    }
};
class Area : public Rectangle {
   private:
    float area;

   public:
    void calc_area() { area = length * width; }
    void result() { cout << "Area = " << area << endl; }
};
class Perimeter : public Rectangle {
   private:
    float perimeter;

   public:
    void calc_peri() { perimeter = 2 * (length + width); }
    void result() { cout << "Perimeter = " << perimeter << endl; }
};
int main() {
    Rectangle R1;
    Area* A1;
    Perimeter P1;
    Rectangle* ptr;
    R1.getdata();
    ptr = &R1;
    A1 = static_cast<Area*>(ptr);
    // or:
    // A1 = (Area*)ptr;
    ptr->Rectangle::result();
}
```

Comment: I am not using virtual. Therefore, I expect the ptr->result to display the result() of the Rectangle class not that of the area class

Comment: Yes but you are doing reading data into `R1` which you are not using later. See my updated answer for explanation in the code and accept my answer if you've found it useful.

Comment: @REACHUS You shouldn't replace the question with your answer. I have rolled it back.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, I intended to paste a `clang-format`ted version of OP's code but somehow pasted my answer code ;). Fixed it now, together with some formatting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ptr points to the address of a child of class Rectangle (the Area class) and therefore it calls the member (result) of the object it refers to (A1 of type Area)

Comment: No, `result` is non-virtual, so it will be called on the base class.

Comment: Yes it should call the result of base class.
But the output is 
length=some address
width=some address

Comment: Rather it should give
Length = (Value input by user)
Width= (Value input by user)